# string to table

Tags: string, lua, lua-table

I know this is a really weird question,
but say i have this type of strings

```
local string_1 = "{ [name] = "string_1", [color] = "red" }"
local string_2 = "{ [name] = "string_2", [color] = "blue" }"
local string_3 = "{ [name] = "string_3", [color] = "green" }"
```

can i use table.insert or something to turn them into this

```
local table_1 = {
    { [name] = "string_1", [color] = "red" };
    { [name] = "string_2", [color] = "blue" };
    { [name] = "string_3", [color] = "green" };
}
```

Comment: I assume that the strings are actually something like `"{ [name] = \"string_1\", [color] = \"red\" }"`?

Comment: Also, did you mean to have the keys be references to variables `name` and `color` rather than being the strings `name` and `color`?

Answer (score 2):

Those strings appear to be Lua code. Assuming the format of these strings is fixed, i.e. you can't pick JSON or some other representation, then the right thing to do is probably to simply load them as Lua code and execute them. You'll probably want to sandbox the code though, depending on where these strings come from.

The way to do this differs between Lua 5.1 and Lua 5.2. Which version are you using?

---

Here's an example of doing it in Lua 5.1. I'm assuming here that your sample input is actually not what you intended, and that `name` and `color` were meant to be string keys, not references to variables. If they are variables, you'll need to muck with the environment.

```
local strings = {
    "{ name = \"string_1\", color = \"red\" }",
    "{ name = \"string_1\", color = \"red\" }",
    "{ name = \"string_3\", color = \"green\" }"
}

-- parses a string that represents a Lua table and returns the table
local function parseString(str)
    local chunk = loadstring("return " .. str)
    -- Sandbox the function. Does it need any environment at all?
    -- Sample input doesn't need an environment. Let's make it {} for now.
    setfenv(chunk, {})
    return chunk()
end

local tables = {}
for _, str in ipairs(strings) do
    table.insert(tables, parseString(str))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have some JSON strings that you need to parse. This can be done by using [LuaJSON](http://luaforge.net/projects/luajson/) or [other](http://www.google.com/?q=lua%20json%20parser)...

Answer (score 0):

This works in both Lua 5.1 & 5.2

```
local string_1 = '{ [name] = "string_1", [color] = "red" }'
local string_2 = '{ [name] = "string_2", [color] = "blue" }'
local string_3 = '{ [name] = "string_3", [color] = "green" }'

local function str2tbl(str)
   return assert((loadstring or load)('return '..str:gsub('%[(.-)]','["%1"]')))()
end

local table_1 = {}
table.insert(table_1, str2tbl(string_1))
table.insert(table_1, str2tbl(string_2))
table.insert(table_1, str2tbl(string_3))
```

Comment: Depending on the source of these strings, this could be quite dangerous to do since you're not sandboxing.

Comment: Also, this doesn't work in Lua 5.1. `load()` can't take a string.